# MySQL - Selecting rows with a minimum number of occurences

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand_name FROM masterdata WHERE in_stock = '1' ORDER BY brand_name
```

It works well, except that I get far too many results. How do I limit this such that rather than just looking for distinct entries, it will only give me distinct entries that exist a minimum of 3 times (for example)?

Basically, if the column had this data...

```
brand_name
==========
apple
banana
apple
apple
orange
banana
orange
orange
```

...my current query would return "apple, banana, orange". How do I get it such that it only returns "apple, orange" (ignoring banana because it has less than three occurrences)?

I'm using PHP to build the query, if it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Something like this (off-the-cuff and untested):

```
SELECT brand_name
  FROM masterdata
 WHERE in_stock = '1'
 GROUP BY brand_name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
 ORDER BY brand_name
```

Comment: That's excellent - it works, thanks! Just one further question if you would be so kind: what would my query be if I wanted to show the first 15 entries in brand_name with the highest frequency, but ordered alphabetically (rather than by frequency)?

So now, I am not defining the minimum number of occurrences, but rather the top 15 entries with the highest number of occurrences.

Comment: @RC: that should be a new question.